# How to find failed site load information in IIS 10? Logging isn't producing any logs and no event viewer events

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-10

On a new 2016 server, I added a few websites to Port 80 using the same server IP address.  If I leave off one of the host names, the site will launch and I will get a log.  If I have a host name, it returns with "This page can't be displayed" and no logging or events.

I've tried to add logging on the sites, added trace logging on the sites and have watched calls with WireShark and am seeing nothing.  I was able to do this on our Dev server just fine but our Stage server will not display a site if I have a host name.

Site bindings: Type: http, Host Name: test1, Port: 80, IP Address: 10.10.10.10
Site bindings: Type: http, Host Name: test2, Port: 80, IP Address: 10.10.10.10
This results in no site and no logs.

Site bindings: Type: http, Host Name: , Port: 80, IP Address: 10.10.10.10
Site bindings: Type: http, Host Name: test2, Port: 80, IP Address: 10.10.10.10
This results in the first site to launch and create a 200 in the IIS logs.  If I try to launch test2, it fails with a 401.1 Unauthorized.

I expected to see some sort of Event Viewer event or IIS logs but am getting nothing.

Comment: Review what's the meaning behind your site bindings and then you might get some hints, https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/binding-diagnostics.html

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the 'page not found' error means 404 error status. That means the browser couldn't find the server during the url.

According to your binding details, I found you bind the site with the hostname test1 and test2.

Normally, the hostname means the domain for your IIS web application. If you don't buy the domain and add the setting to map the domain with your server's IP address, other computer couldn't access the web site by using the domain.

If you just want to test the domain in local computer, you could try to modify the hosts file in your C disk.

The paht as below:

```
C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc
```

You should add two records and try to use the host name to access your web site again.

```
127.0.0.1   test1
127.0.0.1   test2
```

Comment: Thanks @Brando.  I didn't have to modify the host file but did find a MSDN blog about listing all possible host names in the bindings.  This resolved successfully for me.  `10.10.10.10    test1    port 443   and also  10.10.10.10    test1.domain.local.pvt   port 443`

Comment: Do you mean you use the netsh http to open the right port?

Comment: no, the port was open.  It was related to how our internal certs were set up and how our load balancer was configured. By adding both domains, 1 fully qualified and 1 common, on port 443, it resolved in IIS.